# Countable union of rectifiable sets

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> A bounded set $S\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is called **rectifiable** if $\int_S1$ exists (the integral here is Riemann integral.) Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is the union of the countable collection of rectifiable sets $S_1,S_2,\cdots$. Show that $S_1\cup \cdots\cup S_n$ is rectifiable, and give an example showing that $S$ need not be rectifiable.

To show that $S_1\cup \cdots\cup S_n$ is rectifiable, it suffices to show that the union of two rectifiable sets is rectifiable. But this follows from the fact that if $f$ is integrable over $A$ and over $B$, then it is integrable over $A\cup B$.

For the second part, I'm thinking of something like $S\in\mathbb{R}$, $S_1=[0,1],S_2=[1,1+1/2],S_3=[2,2+1/3], \cdots$, but the problem here is that the set $S$ is not bounded. What could an example be?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Riemann. I've edited to add that.

Comment: @MikaH. And you define $$\int_S 1=\int_A\chi_S$$ where $A$ is a rectangle containing $S$? In such case, $\int_S1=\int_A\chi_S$ exists $\iff \partial S$ has measure zero $\iff \partial S$ has Jordan content zero. Such sets are usually called Jordan measurable.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yes, that is the definition I use. Indeed, the condition is equivalent to the boundary having measure zero.

Comment: Note your set will be $[0,3/2]$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Oh, it was just a typo. Edited. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if for each $S_i$, $\displaystyle \int_{S_i}1$ exists, for each $\epsilon >0$ we can find a *finite* number of closed rectangles $\{R_{1i},\ldots,R_{k_ii}\}$ that cover $\partial S_i$ and whose volumes sum less than $\epsilon$. This is due to compactness of $\partial S_i$. In such a case, any finite union of such sets will have this property too. What about this? Enumarate the rationals in $[0,1]$, and draw lines from each of them to their pair in the line trough $y=1$. Then consider the set that is the union of all this lines. It should look like a "codebar" of rational endpoints. This is inside the unit square, but the Riemann integral cannot exist. Indeed, the boundary of this set is $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Comment: Looks good to me! Actually, can't we just look in one dimension then, and take all the rationals in $[0,1]$? Then the boundary should be $[0,1]$.

Comment: @MikaH. Yes. Thought the lines would make it more interesting. =)

Comment: Another way to do this could be using?:
 Let $S_1 , ... , S_k$ be bounded sets in $R^n$; assume
$S_i\cap S_j$ has measure zero whenever $i\neq j$. Let $S = S_1\cup · · · \cup S_k$. If $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable over each set $S_i$ , then f is integrable over $S$ and $\int_{S}f=\int_{S_1}f+\int_{S_2}f+...+\int_{S_k}f$?

Comment: What you want to say to show that $S$ does not need to be rectifiable is that if we take the rationals in $[0,1]$, then $\{x\}$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ is rectifiable but $A:=\bigcup_{x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]}\{x\}$ is not rectifiable since $\int_{A}f$ does not exist since in this case it (f) would be like the Dirichlet function?